# To persist data within a single request (from controller into the view), what is the difference between ViewData (or ViewBag) vs HttpContext.Items?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, httpcontext

**HttpContext.Items**:

> Gets or sets a key/value collection that can be used to share data
> within the scope of this request.

To persist values within a single request I usually make use of ViewBag (or ViewData).

**HttpContext** is accessible in the **controller action**:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult About()
    {
        var pathBase = HttpContext....;

        // ...

        return View();
    }
}
```

It is also available in the **razor view**:

```
@{
    var username = Context....;

    // ...
}
```

Additionally, other methods (invoked by the controller action) can use the values by injecting the `IHttpContextAccessor` and using the HttpContext.

What is the difference between using HttpContext.Items vs ViewBag (or ViewData) to send the data from controller to view?

Answer (score 0):

**ViewData:**

1. ViewData is derived from the ViewDataDictionary class and is basically a Dictionary object i.e., Keys and Values where Keys are String while Values will be objects.
2. Data is stored as Object in ViewData.
3. While retrieving the data it needs to be Type Cast to its original type as the data is stored as the object and it also requires NULL checks while retrieving.
4. ViewData is used for passing value from Controller to View.
5. ViewData is available only for Current Request. It will be destroyed on redirection.
6. ViewData is Faster than ViewBag.

**ViewBag:**

1. ViewBag is a Wrapper built around ViewData.
2. ViewBag is a dynamic property and it makes use of the C# 4.0 dynamic features.
3. While retrieving, there is no need for Type Casting data.
4. ViewBag is used for passing value from Controller to View.
5. ViewBag is available only for Current Request. It will be destroyed on redirection.

**HttpContext.Items:**

1. Only lasts for the duration of the request, but it is global to everything in that request.
2. HttpContext.Items is designed to store a Key-Value-Pair and is intended to share items within the scope of the current request.

In a single request, if there is no special need, just simply pass data from the controller to the view, there is no significant difference between the three.You can freely choose to use `Httpcontext.Items` or `ViewData` (`ViewBag`), the purpose of both is the same.